WSImport with null check and create new element in arraylist
Hi do we have any way where we can remove this null check.
As when we use AXIS2 it's working fine but as it's not support jakarta so we moved to Springws with generating wsimport, But here when pojo create it will check null and create new 0 element. On client side they have check array != null at many places so we can't tell them to check empty along with null.
Only solution is to get rid of this null check and create new 0th element.
Please HELP, Thanks in Advance.
wsdlFiles.each { wsdlFile ->
ant {
taskdef(name: 'wsimport',
classname: 'com.sun.tools.ws.ant.WsImport',
classpath: configurations.jaxws.asPath
)
wsimport(
keep: true,
destdir: jaxwsSourceDir,
extension: "true",
verbose: true,
wsdl: "${projectDir}/src/main/xsd/Service/"+ wsdlFile+ ".wsdl",
xnocompile: true
) {
binding(dir:"${projectDir}/src/jaxws", includes:"dataTypeBinding.xml,jaxwsHolderBinding.xml")
xjcarg(value: "-XautoNameResolution")
}
}
}
